# SimpleXML ElementMap creates null elements

Tags: java, android, robolectric, simple-framework

I'm having a problem with SimpleXML on Android inserting null elements into a HashMap using @ElementMap.

Starting with the XML:

```
<sysinfo>
    <queues>
        <queue id="1" displayname="Queue 1" status="true">Sample Queue 1</queue>
        <queue id="2" displayname="Queue 2" status="false">Sample Queue 2</queue>
    </queues>
</sysinfo>
```

I've removed a bunch of things, but that's the gist of it, The two classes involved are SysInfo and Queue:

```
@Root
public class SysInfo {
    @ElementMap(key="id", attribute=true)
    protected Map<Integer, Queue> queues = new HashMap<>();
}

@Root
public class Queue {
    @Attribute protected String id;
    @Attribute(name = "displayname") protected String displayName;
    @Attribute(name = "status") protected boolean available;
    @Text protected String name;
}
```

And finally, the test code that reads the xml using SimpleXML:

```
private InputStream getXmlStream(String fileName) throws IOException {
    ShadowApplication application = Robolectric.getShadowApplication();
    assertNotNull(application);

    InputStream input = application.getAssets().open(fileName);
    assertNotNull(input);

    return input;
}

@Test public void testMinimalQueues() throws Exception {
    SysInfo sysinfo = new Persister().read(SysInfo.class, getXmlStream("minimal_test.xml"));
    Map<Integer, Queue> queues = sysinfo.queues;

    assertNotNull(queues);
    assertEquals(2, queues.size());

    Queue queue = queues.get(1);
    assertNotNull(queue);
    assertEquals(1, queue.id);
    assertEquals("Queue 1", queue.displayName);
    assertEquals(true, queue.available);
    assertEquals("Sample Queue 1", queue.name);
}
```

When I step through the `testMinimalQueues` function, queues has 2 elements in it, with the correct keys (1 and 2) but the actual values are `null`, and sure enough, the `queues.get(1)` call returns `null`

I've tried various combinations of `entry` and `value` in the `@ElementMap` annotation, but nothing seems to work.

This seems like a really obvious and simple use case, what am I missing here?

One more, perhaps relevant, detail, if I replace the `ElementMap` with an `ElementList` of `ArrayList<Queue>` it all works, but I lose the mapping functionality.  So it seems like the parsing of `Queue` works as expected.

Comment: David, does it parse wrongly in Robolectric? Or it is general problem with simple xml?

Comment: The XML is correct.  The parsing of the individual Queue elements is correct (I can put the elements into an ElementList instead of an ElementMap and everything is fine).  But it seems like simple xml isn't assigning the value into the Map correctly.